# Illegal Argument on Date.addDays when called from lightning

Tags: apex, lightning

I have a small Lightning component that calls an Apex function when a button is clicked.

The Apex function queries a list op opportunities and changes their closeDate with the addDays function. When this function is called from my lightning component, it results in a `System.UnexpectedException: Illegal arguments`.

However, when I call the same function from the Execute Anonymous Window in the developer console there is no problem.

Here is my code:

testComponent.cmp:

```
<aura:component controller="TestComponentController">
    <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="test" onclick="{!c.test}"/>
</aura:component>
```

testComponentController.js:

```
({
    test : function test(component, event, helper) 
    {
        "use strict";
        console.log("test");

        var action = component.get("c.moveDate");

        action.setParams({
            "days": 6
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function updateSessionCallback(response)
        {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS")
                window.alert("OK");
            else
                window.alert("Failed with state: " + state);
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

TestComponentController.apxc:

```
public class TestComponentController 
{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void moveDate(Integer days)
    {
        System.debug('moveDate ' + days);
        List<Opportunity> opportunities = 
            [SELECT Id, CloseDate
             FROM Opportunity];
        for (Opportunity o : opportunities)
        {
            System.debug('from ' + o.CloseDate);
            if (o.CloseDate != null)
                o.CloseDate = o.CloseDate.addDays(days);
            System.debug('to ' + o.CloseDate);
        }
        update opportunities;
    }
}
```

And logging (from /aura):

```
09:52:25:002 USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|moveDate 6
09:52:25:016 USER_DEBUG [12]|DEBUG|from 2017-07-28 00:00:00
09:52:25:017 FATAL_ERROR System.UnexpectedException: Illegal arguments
09:52:25:000 FATAL_ERROR Class.TestComponentController.moveDate: line 14, column 1
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening and how I can work around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please exchange your line with this piece of code in apex controller.hope it will help you.

```
o.CloseDate = (o.CloseDate).addDays(Integer.valueOf(days));
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Though I don't really understand why. As far as I can see days is already an Integer so this _should_ make no difference.